# brew services httpd22 and postgresql shown as started, but can not be connected to

Tags: macos, mac, apache-http-server, homebrew, osx-el-capitan

Earlier I was successfully using VM Fusion with CentOS Linux VM for web development needs.

However now I would like to switch to [homebrew](http://brew.sh) package manager.

So I have installed it and then run the following commands:

```
brew update
brew install postgres
brew install homebrew/apache/httpd22
brew install homebrew/php/php53
brew tap homebrew/services
```

When I run `brew services list` afterwards, they are show as "started":

[image: bash screenshot]

However `netstat -an` does not show any service running at port 8080 and trying to connect to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` with browser does not work.

Same for PostgreSQL: I can run `psql`, but it can't find the `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` socket.

What could be the reason? I have rebooted my Macbook Air several times and the firewall is off in "Security & Privacy" settings:

[image: settings]

Also while in troubleshooting process I have tried

```
xcode-select --install
brew update
brew update
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)
```

and submitted the same question as [issue 50065](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/50065) at Github.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the postmaster.pid file of a crashed process still appears in place:

> FATAL:  could not open log file
>   "/var/log/postgresql/pg_log/postgresql-2016-11-06_011112.log": No such
>   file or directory

Was difficult to see this because the logs where turned off. PostgreSQL was running, indeed, but crashing:

> ... com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.postgresql[98074]):
>   Service exited with abnormal code: 1

SOLUTION:
just exec this in the shell

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```